# C recover compiles but return null for the files read

Tags: c, cs50

Trying to solve this problem i keep finding the same errors:

:) recover.c exists.

:) recover.c compiles.

:) handles lack of forensic image

:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
000.jpg not found

:( recovers middle images correctly
001.jpg not found

:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
049.jpg not found

That makes me think that the files are not been read or opened at all and i can't find why because the code compiles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //checks if there is an input
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("./recover Usage: ./recover image \n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        char* filename = argv[1];
        FILE* input = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (strcmp(filename, "card.raw") != 0)
        {
            printf("Unable to open: %s\n", filename);
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create buffer
            uint8_t buffer[512];

            //Create pointer for the buffer
            FILE* output = NULL;

            // create 8 bytes file
            char files[8];

            //Files counters
            int jpeg_counter = 0;

            //Check
            while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input))
            {
                //check 4 first bytes of file to see if they contain the jpg signature
                if ((buffer[0] == 0xff) && (buffer[1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
                {
                    if (output != NULL) {
                        // sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...) and "03i" means 3 digits in format 001, 002...
                        sprintf(files, "%03i.jpg", jpeg_counter);
                        //use created pointer to save jpeg files from input folder card.raw
                        output = fopen(filename, "w");
                        //add jpeg to the new buffer using ouput pointer
                        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, output);
                        // update counter
                        jpeg_counter++;
                    }
                    else //no more files to read(end of folder array) - or no images found.
                    {
                        printf("Could not open file\n");
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            fclose(output);
            fclose(input);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are opening the file only if `output != NULL`.  You probably want `if( output == NULL )` instead.

Comment: Compiles too but it return the same errors. And not sure why i would open it if output == NULL(though of it as "ok no file found.") that is happening.

Comment: `printf("Unable to open: %s\n", filename);` That is not true. You do not check if you could open it but only if it has the name you expect. Basically the name should not bother you as long as you can open it.

Comment: `if (output== NULL)` does not mean "No file found" but it means "I did not try to open any output file before, it's a good time to do it now!"

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger and see where your execution flow is. Be prepared for suprises.

Comment: When you return 2 input is not closed.

Comment: It should be `fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), input)`, and you should store the number which `fread` returns. Then write that many characters to output file `fwrite(buffer, 1, read_count, output);` You also want to open the file in binary mode `"rb"` and `"wb"`. Test this with a smaller simple program.

Comment: fread may return less than 4 bytes in which case your program will be incorrect.

Comment: What's the format of card.raw?  The code seems to assume a jpeg per  512 bytes.  If that is the case, then you should open/close in the loop, otherwise I suggest a double loop one to iterate over files and inner loop to iterate over content of a file.

Comment: I'd expect best to open in binary mode: `fopen(filename, "r");` --> `fopen(filename, "rb");`.

Comment: _Always_ check if `fopen` succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t buffer[512];
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input)
```

This should be change to: `fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), input)`. This way `fread` will read up to 512 bytes. When it gets to the end of file, it reads whatever is left, for example 1 byte, and returns that number. Likewise, `fwrite` should change. It should write the same number which was read earlier.

Open the file in binary mode.

If `fopen` fails then stop immediately.

Check the file header only once, not every read loop.

Your condition for checking the file header may have a typo `(buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0`. Checking the first 3 bytes should be okay.

```
int main()
{
    FILE* input = fopen("input.jpg", "rb");
    if (!input)
    { perror("input error"); return 0; }

    FILE* output = fopen("output.jpg", "wb");
    if (!output)
    { perror("output error"); fclose(input); return 0; }

    uint8_t buf[1000];
    int check_header = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        size_t read_count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), input);
        if (!read_count)
            break;
        if (check_header)
        {
            if (buf[0] == 0xff && buf[1] == 0xd8 && buf[2] == 0xff)
                // && buf[3] == 0xe0 ?
            { printf("header is okay\n"); }
            else
            { printf("not okay\n"); break; }
            check_header = 0; //don't check header again
        }
        fwrite(buf, 1, read_count, output);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd think `if (!read_count ) break;` should be before `if (check_header)`.

Comment: And I'd +1 again if I could for not writing bug-prone code from cramming `fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), input)`.  Why on God's good Earth is that style taught?  It's not only bug-prone, it makes debugging so much harder.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks fixed it.

Comment: You cannot do `output = fopen(); if (! output ) {fclose(input); perror...`. `fclose` may modify `errno`, making the subsequent call to `perror` potentially print a completely incorrect error message.  You must call `perror` before any intervening calls which may modify `errno`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I didn't know that. Updated based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another attempt at a solution, however, it only writes out the first 512 bytes (unlike the original) but I don't think jpeg uses 512 bytes fixed chunks so neither the op or or @BarmakShemirani solution would work as expected.  `(buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0` means [variable sized, application specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) and there is a reference that data is laid out like TIFF,  In either case op did not share `card.raw` so whatever format is used would be speculation:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME_LEN 8

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int r = 0;
    FILE *input = NULL;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("./recover Usage: ./recover image \n");
        r = 1;
        goto out;
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];
    input = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!strcmp(filename, "card.raw")) {
        printf("Unable to open: %s\n", filename);
        r = 2;
        goto out;
    }

    for(int jpeg_counter = 0; !r; jpeg_counter++) {
        uint8_t buffer[512];
        size_t n = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input);
        // use an existing library instead?
        if(
            n < 4 ||
            buffer[0] != 0xff ||
            buffer[1] != 0xd8 ||
            buffer[2] != 0xff ||
            (buffer[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0
        ) {
            printf("invalid header\n");
            r = 3;
            break;
        }

        char filename2[FILENAME_LEN];
        if(snprintf(filename2, FILENAME_LEN, "%03i.jpg", jpeg_counter) >= FILENAME_LEN) {
            printf("%s: output filename truncated", filename);
            r = 4;
            break;
        };

        FILE *output = fopen(filename2, "wb");
        if(!output) {
            printf("%s: fopen failed\n", filename);
            r = 5;
            break;
        }
        // TBD: replace with a loop once we figure out
        // how a given file is terminated.
        if(fwrite(buffer, n, 1, output) != n) {
            printf("%s: write failed\n", filename);
            r = 6;
        }
        fclose(output);
    }
out:
    if(input) fclose(input);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Tried those and got the same error. What surprisingly worked for me was to refactor even more the code and give use of the counter  for the if conditions as shown below.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//checks if there is an input
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf(".Usage: Looking for card.raw \n");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    char* filename = argv[1];
    FILE* input;
    input = fopen(filename, "r");
    //to track if it fails to open
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file");
        return 2;
    }

    //Create buffer. Unsigned int variable type. Array of 512 bytes
    uint8_t buffer[512];

    //Create pointer for the buffer.
    FILE* output = NULL;

    // create 8 bytes file
    char files[8];

    //Files counters
    int jpeg_counter = 0;

    //Check
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input))
    {
            //check 4 first bytes of file to see if they contain the jpg signature
            if ((buffer[0] == 0xff) && (buffer[1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
            {
                if (jpeg_counter != 0)
                {
                    fclose(output);
                }
                // sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...) and "03i" means 3 digits in format 001, 002...
                sprintf(files, "%03i.jpg", jpeg_counter);
                //use created pointer to save jpeg files from input folder card.raw
                output = fopen(files, "w");
                //add jpeg to the new buffer using ouput pointer
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, output);
                // update counter
                jpeg_counter++;
            } else if (jpeg_counter != 0)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, output);
            }

    }

    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

}